# Clickhouse code 32 DB::Exception: Attempt to read after eof

Tags: sql, database, dictionary, clickhouse

I created a dictionary on Clickhouse using the following script:

```sql
CREATE DICTIONARY IF NOT EXISTS default.testDICT
(
    -- attributes
)
PRIMARY KEY DATETIME, SOMEID, SOMEID2
SOURCE(CLICKHOUSE(HOST 'localhost' PORT 9000 USER 'default' PASSWORD '' DB 'default' TABLE 'test'))
LIFETIME(MIN 0 MAX 300)
LAYOUT(COMPLEX_KEY_HASHED())
```

The table test has approximately 19 000 000 rows.

And when I try to execute a select

```sql
SELECT * FROM testDICT
```

, which also loads the dictionary if I understood well, it sends me the following error:

```sh
Exception on client:
Code: 32. DB::Exception: Attempt to read after eof: while receiving packet from clickhouse-server:9000

Connecting to clickhouse-server:9000 as user default.
Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (clickhouse-server:9000)
```

Do you know what it means and also how can I correct it?

Comment: I think this is the wrong way to using a dictionary because the count of rows is huge. I suspect even using [cached layout](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries/external-dictionaries/external-dicts-dict-layout/#cache) (as @Denis Zhuravlev suggested) does not help because of the [hit rate](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/system-tables/#system_tables-dictionaries) will be small that be pretty not effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

19 000 000 rows is too many for a dictionary. Probably it will require 10-20GB RAM.

So your CH crashed or killed by OOM killer. Check `sudo dmesg|tail -100`

Try cached dictionaries layout to load only part of 19 000 000 into memory at once.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this blog, try to do the following before inserting: `set max_insert_threads=32;`
I first also got the same error, but after I changed max_insert_threads, I successfully inserted almost 200GB of data.

https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-and-redshift-face-off-again-in-nyc-taxi-rides-benchmark